# How to switch from current tab to next opened tab in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

How to switch from current tab to next opened tab in similar browser in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use **Select Window** keyword to navigate tabs in a browser using  [selenium2Library](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html).

Here, Select Window keyword selects the tab based on title of the page.

> By default the locator is matched against window handle, name, title,
>   and URL. Matching is done in that order and the the first matching
>   window is selected.

**Sample Scenario**

```
*** Settings ***
Library SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
NAVIGATE TABS
    OPEN BROWSER  <<URL>>  FF
    Click Element   << ELEMENT WHICH EXISTS >>
    Select Window    title=<<TITLE NAME>>
```

If we do not know the title/url of the new Tab AND want to navigate to the last tab then, you can try with the following snippet of code,

> If the [locator is NEW](https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window) (case-insensitive), the latest opened window is
>   selected. It is an error if this is the same as the current window.

```
${handle} = Select Window   NEW # Select latest opened window
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but in my case <Title Name> is not known it is dynamic

Comment: for that I have done this  ${Windowtitles[${total_tabs}-1]}
firstly, I have got all the WindowTitles and count the number of all opened tabs as total_tabs and using above code I got my latest opened tab.

Comment: If the answer has helped you , please accept the same.https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch back to the original tab:

```
Navigate Tabs
    Go To           <<url>>
    Click Element   xpath=<<xpath>>       # opens a new tab
    ${tab1}=        Select Window    NEW  # switch to new tab and get original tab handle 
    Sleep   10                            # do stuff in new tab
    Select Window       ${tab1}           # switch back to original tab
```